# Differentiation of integrals over time dependent regions

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-derivative

Is there a general equation relating
$$
\int_{\Omega(t)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} dx
$$
and
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \int_{\Omega(t)} f dx
$$
If $\Omega$ is constant and $f$ is smooth (edit: and bounded), then these are known to be equal. How, if at all, does the time dependence of $\Omega$ change the relationship of these two integrals?

Comment: "If $\Omega$ is constant and $f$ is smooth" -- I think you want some boundedness assumptions somewhere.

Comment: You're right. I was thinking of $f$ as being defined on a compact set containing $\Omega$, but it's just as well to include the boundedness assumption.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Thanks. If you want the reputation, you can post this link with a little elaboration as an answer and I'll accept it.